# Which variable first in bivariate regression?

Tags: r

I'm an R beginner and I want to do a bivariate regression using this function:

`model <- lm( x ~ y, data = data)`

`summary(model)`

My question is: Does it matter which of the two variables I put in first (x)?
And if it matters do i put in the Dependent or Independent/Predictor variable first?

Edit: Also does it matter for a CrossTable?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. The dependent variable needs to go on the left of the `~`. See the help page `?formula` for lots more detail and explanations.

Comment: In words: a linear model of the dependent variable regressed on the independent variable(s).  In code: `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)`

Comment: And thats’s not a *bivariate* regression.

Comment: Thank you all!
@Limey you are right I mean Linear